# Concurrent query execution issue with a Spring boot application having multiple datasources with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, generics

So my application has a `GenericRepository` class with a `JdbcTemplate` Initialized with a single datasource and has multiple generic methods  (`find()`, `add()`, `update()`, `delete()` etc.). I extend this class in my DAO(s) and use those generic methods to execute sql queries (i pass query and the query parameters, if any, from my DAO to those methods). Now here comes a 2nd datasource. Now i have to initialize my `JdbcTemplate` object with another datasource whenever i am required to query in that datasource and then reinitialize the primary datasource when the query is executed and I no longer need that datasource. But the problem would arise during Concurrency. Lets say, When a User 1 wants to query in 2nd datasource and initializes it, now before the User1's query is executed, User2 starts executing his query which requires connection of the primary datasource but jdbcTemplate is initialized secondary connection and User2's query would not work or throw some error. 
How can this be solved without changing any implementation of Generic methods in my GenericRepository ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Also please use paragraphs and shorter sentences in your descriptions. Currently it is quite unreadable.